# how to read un-named object from BindingContext

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, custom-model-binder

I need to implement Custom model binding and so trying to implement `IModelBinder` for `.Net Core 2.1 API` application.

`Model` class -

```
  [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(PersonBinder))]
  public class Person
  {
     public name {get;set;}
     public address {get;set;}
  }
```

`API` method -

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("process")]
 public async Task<ActionResult<int>> ProcessAsync([ModelBinder(typeof(PersonBinder))]Person person)
 {
     ...
 }
```

Bind Model method -

```
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName; //modelName is empty string
    ...
}
```

Postman request that i use for testing has `JSON` object in the `body` and the simplest form of it looks like this -

```
{
    "name": "name1"
    "address": "address1" 
}
```

Please note that this request comes from the existing legacy client which i have no control of and the `JSON` object that will be coming as a body in `POST` will have no name.

In `QuickWatch` in `VisualStudio` i also see that `bindingContext.ValueProvider.Count is 1` and `bindingContext.ModelMetadata` has `Parameter` of `person` and `Type` of `Person` and `bindingContext.FieldName` is `person`. And surprisingly `bindingProvider.Result` is `Failed` and `bindingContext.ModelName` is always `String.Empty`

Can anyone please help me get the `ModelName` from `BindingContext`. And if there is no way to get `ModelName` in this situation then how can i read the `Person` object from `BindingContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the best way to read posted parameters and since i did not get any response to this question, i will post how i did it, if it can be helpful to anyone else

```
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var bodyString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var person = bodyString.DeSerialize<Person>(); //this is custom logic to de-serialize to object from JSON string

                //write your model binding logic here...

                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(person);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```